# Why is "banging his nose" possible but "answering the phone'' not possible?

Tags: meaning, grammar, participles, ing

1. He ran into the wall, banging his nose.
2. He got out of bed, answering the phone.

Why is the first one possible but is the second one not possible?

Comment: Where did you hear that one of these two is not possible?

Comment: It would normally be, "He got out of bed **to answer** the phone."

Comment: I have often gotten out of bed, answering the phone. This generally puts me in a bad mood for the rest of the morning.

Answer (score 3):

Both are grammatical.

He banged his nose  while he ran into the wall.  So you can say "He ran into the wall, banging his nose."

If he answered the phone while he got out of bed you can say "He got out of bed, answering the phone."  But if he answered the phone *after* he got out of bed, then you would not say that.

Comment: I'm unconvinced.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: I am. Phones do not have a locational aspect like they used to: cell phones are often on one's person or next to them even in bed anymore.

Comment: @Yorik I understand the possiblity but disagree that writing that phrase is either unambiguous or lacking in clumsiness.  "He answered the phone, getting out of bed in the process" seems much smoother to me.

Answer (score 1):

The first describes and unintended (I hope!) action and a resulting condition.  The second describes an intended (I hope!) action taken to be able to complete another intended action.  That's why the second should be, as Mark Hubbard commented, " ... to answer the phone."

Now, if you planned to stay in bed but fell out while reaching for the phone, I'd write "He fell out of bed while answering the phone."

Comment: Running can cause banging, but getting up doesn't cause answering, unless you consider tripping over (or stepping on) the phone as 'taking a call'.